# insert a prepare statment in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
insert into droicombo (droidid,droidarmyid)  
(prepare stmt from 'select droidID,1 from Droid where DTypeID=11 limit ?';
execute stmt using @l1);
```

I want to insert this in the table. How can I go about it. If I execute only

```
prepare stmt from 'select droidID,1 from Droid where DTypeID=11 limit ?';
execute stmt using @l1
```

it gives me the result. But I want to insert the result in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select + insert in the same query. Assuming your `droicombo` table has two columns `droidid`,`droidarmyid` and you want to fetch the result from the query `select droidID,1 from Droid where DTypeID=11 limit 100` and insert it into `droicombo` table, you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO droicombo(droidid,droidarmyid) SELECT droidID,1 FROM Droid WHERE DTypeID=11 LIMIT 100
```

For more information, you can see MySQL documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I want to insert the prepare statement because limit is a variable. Its is not 100

Comment: How do you set the limit then?

Comment: It is a variable. Depends on the previous query.

Comment: What do you mean by previous query?